# Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, types

I am brand new to typescript, and I have two classes. In the parent class I have:

```
abstract class Component {
  public deps: any = {};
  public props: any = {};

  public setProp(prop: string): any {
    return <T>(val: T): T => {
      this.props[prop] = val;
      return val;
    };
  }
}
```

In the child class I have:

```
class Post extends Component {
  public toggleBody: string;

  constructor() {
    this.toggleBody = this.setProp('showFullBody');
  }

  public showMore(): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(true);
  }

  public showLess(): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(false);
  }
}
```

Both showMore and ShowLess give me the error, "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature."

But the function that setProp returns DOES have a call signature, I think? I think I'm misunderstanding something important about typings of functions, but I don't know what it is.

Thanks!

Comment: `togglrBody` should not be a string, since you want it to be a function

Comment: @eavidan yes it is a function that actually returns a boolean. I originally thought it would return a string. So what do I change it to?

Comment: Whatever setProp returns, which seems like `<T>(val: T) => T`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The function that it returns has a call signature, but you told Typescript to completely ignore that by adding `: any` in its signature.

Comment: Ok progress, Thanks! Now I get "error TS2322: Type '<T>(val: T) => T' is not assignable to type 'boolean'." If I remove the :any. I think this is why I added :any in the first place. I actually still get the original errors as well.

Comment: If I do this and change `public toggleBody: boolean;` to `public toggleBody: any;` it works.

Comment: @Justin why did you expect anything else? You claim `this.toggleBody` should return `boolean`, but that's not consistent with the return value of `setProp` that you've assigned to it. You seem to be just randomly throwing in types without thinking about what you actually want to send and return.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ok yes that does make sense. In this case it returns a boolean, but in general it returns any. So I have to use any?

Comment: @Justin: No; you need to use templates.

Comment: Does making it `: void` also tell TS to ignore it?

Comment: @Noitidart: No; that means it returns nothing.

Comment: This response would benefit from explaining the right way to do things, with an example.

Answer (score 42):

> "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature."

In your code :

```
class Post extends Component {
  public toggleBody: string;

  constructor() {
    this.toggleBody = this.setProp('showFullBody');
  }

  public showMore(): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(true);
  }

  public showLess(): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(false);
  }
}
```

You have `public toggleBody: string;`. You cannot call a `string` as a function. Hence errors on : `this.toggleBody(true);` and `this.toggleBody(false);`

Answer (score 40):

Let's break this down:

1. The error says

   > Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
2. The code:

The problem is in this line `public toggleBody: string;` &

it's relation to these lines:

```
...
return this.toggleBody(true);
...
return this.toggleBody(false);
```

3. The result:

Your saying `toggleBody` is a `string` but then your treating it like something that has a `call signature` (i.e. the structure of something that can be called: lambdas, proc, functions, methods, etc. In JS just function tho.). You need to change the declaration to be `public toggleBody: (arg: boolean) => boolean;`.

**Extra Details:**

"invoke" means your calling or applying a function.

"an expression" in Javascript is basically something that produces a value, so `this.toggleBody()` counts as an expression.

"type" is declared on this line `public toggleBody: string`

"lacks a call signature" this is because your trying to call something `this.toggleBody()` that doesn't have signature(i.e. the structure of something that can be called: lambdas, proc, functions, methods, etc.) that can be called. You said `this.toggleBody` is something that acts like a string.

In other words the error is saying

> Cannot call an expression (this.toggleBody) because it's type (:string) lacks a call signature (bc it has a string signature.)

Comment: This is one of the best answers, ever! I know all of those definitions but when I saw the warning message all those terms, in one dense sentence, were too much for my cluttered brain.

Answer (score 9):

It means you're trying to call something that isn't a function

```
const foo = 'string'
foo() // error
```

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want is:

```
abstract class Component {
  public deps: any = {};
  public props: any = {};

  public makePropSetter<T>(prop: string): (val: T) => T {
    return function(val) {
      this.props[prop] = val
      return val
    }
  }
}

class Post extends Component {
  public toggleBody: (val: boolean) => boolean;

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.toggleBody = this.makePropSetter<boolean>('showFullBody')
  }

  showMore (): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(true)
  }

  showLess (): boolean {
    return this.toggleBody(false)
  }
}
```

The important change is in `setProp` (i.e., `makePropSetter` in the new code).  What you're really doing there is to say: this is a function, which provided with a property name, will return a function which allows you to change that property.

The `<T>` on `makePropSetter` allows you to lock that function in to a specific type.  The `<boolean>` in the subclass's constructor is actually optional.  Since you're assigning to `toggleBody`, and that already has the type fully specified, the TS compiler will be able to work it out on its own.

Then, in your subclass, you call that function, and the return type is now properly understood to be a function with a specific signature.  Naturally, you'll need to have `toggleBody` respect that same signature.

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused when you are requesting a value from something and you put parenthesis at the end, as if it is a function call, yet the value is correctly retrieved without ending parenthesis.  For example, if what you are accessing is a Property 'get' in Typescript.

```
private IMadeAMistakeHere(): void {
    let mynumber = this.SuperCoolNumber();
}

private IDidItCorrectly(): void {
    let mynumber = this.SuperCoolNumber;
}

private get SuperCoolNumber(): number {
    let response = 42;
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a type to your variable and then return.

Eg:

```
const myVariable : string [] = ['hello', 'there'];

const result = myVaraible.map(x=> {
  return
  {
    x.id
  }
});
```

=> Important part is adding the string[] type etc:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. In my case I had inadvertently mixed the ES6 `export default function myFunc` syntax with `const myFunc = require('./myFunc');`.

Using `module.exports = myFunc;` instead solved the issue.