# AngularX TS error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm creating a component like this and I'm getting an error on ng serve/ building.
Do not confuse with error on console as some commenters seem to think.
Th expected behavior is for the code the build and run.

```
TS error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature
```

in the foreach function in `ngOnInit()`

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChartInput, MultiChartInput, ChartColorScheme } from "@shared/models/chart-input";

    @Component({
        selector: 'chart-legend',
        templateUrl: './chart-legend.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./chart-legend.component.css']
    })
    export class ChartLegendComponent implements OnInit {

        @Input()
        public chartInput: ChartInput[] | MultiChartInput[];
        @Input()
        public legendColors: ChartColorScheme;

        public legends: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.chartInput.forEach(
                (item, index) => {
                    this.legends.set(item.name, this.legendColors.domain[index]);
                });
            }
        }

export class ChartInput {
    name: string;
    value: number;

}
export class MultiChartInput {
    name: string;
    series: ChartInput[];
}
export class ChartColorScheme {
    domain: string[];
}
```

Any help that solves is appreciated.
If someone thinks this is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature). Please explain. I dont think so.

Comment: check console.log(this.chartInput) in ngOnInit();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature)

Comment: @orangespark nope.. I'll pass that. Please compare it and mark duplicate. The error is same. but different use case.

Comment: @Ajay ... I want to build for that.. Do u think.??

Comment: is this snippet you are using in your code exactly?

Comment: @orangespark It was. Now i altered the way i do it. But still i like to solve this.

Comment: if this the code exactly then You are missing a paranthesis ")" for foreach

Comment: @orangespark  edited that. that doesnt solve.

Comment: Please provide the code for all the model definitions ChartInput,MultiChartInput,ChartColorScheme

Comment: @orangespark added those code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162148/discussion-between-orangespark-and-jins-peter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known to occur when using union types ([*Microsoft/TypeScript* - Issue #7294](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294)). As explained in the [issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294#issuecomment-190335544):

> This is currently by design because we don't synthesize an intersectional call signature when getting the members of a union type -- only call signatures which are *identical* appear on the unioned type.

In your case, `ChartInput` and `MultiChartInput` do not have compatible signatures because they each have unique attributes; i.e., `ChartInput` has `value: number`, while `MultiChartInput` has `series: ChartInput[]`. You can quickly test this by commenting out those attributes and seeing the error disappear ([demo of experiment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ChartLegendComponent%20%2F*implements%20OnInit*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20chartInput%3A%20ChartInput%5B%5D%20%7C%20MultiChartInput%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20legendColors%3A%20ChartColorScheme%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20legends%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconstructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AngOnInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.chartInput.forEach(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(item%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.legends.set(item.name%2C%20this.legendColors.domain%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fvalue%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MultiChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fseries%3A%20ChartInput%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartColorScheme%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20domain%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)).

To resolve the error while maintaining type safety, change the type of `chartInput` to `(ChartInput | MultiChartInput)[]`:

```
class ChartLegendComponent implements OnInit {
    public chartInput: (ChartInput | MultiChartInput)[];
    ...
}
```

[demo of fix 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ChartLegendComponent%20%2F*implements%20OnInit*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20chartInput%3A%20(ChartInput%20%7C%20MultiChartInput)%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20legendColors%3A%20ChartColorScheme%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20legends%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconstructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AngOnInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.chartInput.forEach(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(item%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.legends.set(item.name%2C%20this.legendColors.domain%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MultiChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20series%3A%20ChartInput%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartColorScheme%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20domain%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

...or cast `this.chartInput`:

```
(this.chartInput as (ChartInput | MultiChartInput)[])
  .forEach(
      (item, index) => {
          this.legends.set(item.name, this.legendColors.domain[index]);
      });
  }
```

[demo of fix 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20ChartLegendComponent%20%2F*implements%20OnInit*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20chartInput%3A%20ChartInput%5B%5D%20%7C%20MultiChartInput%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%40Input()%0D%0Apublic%20legendColors%3A%20ChartColorScheme%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Apublic%20legends%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0D%0Aconstructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AngOnInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(this.chartInput%20as%20(ChartInput%20%7C%20MultiChartInput)%5B%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.forEach(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(item%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.legends.set(item.name%2C%20this.legendColors.domain%5Bindex%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MultiChartInput%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20series%3A%20ChartInput%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20class%20ChartColorScheme%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20domain%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Thanks. I actually had find the fix 1 and solved the issue. but I really wanted to check it could work some other way. thanks for fix 2 and the microsoft's documention on the matter