# Typescript error for type Array:- Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I have created getter-setter as following using typescript in Angular5:-

```
  private _locations: Array<string> = [];

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Getter locations
   * @return {Array<string>}
   */
  public get locations(): Array<string> {
    return this._locations;
  }

  /**
   * Setter locations
   * @param {Array<string>} value
   */
  public set locations(value: Array<string>) {
    this._locations = value;
  }
```

When I try to access method locations

```
this.signUpService.locations();
```

I am getting an error : `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string[]' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: Can u post the code for accessing method 'locations' ?

Comment: like this from  another component :- this.signUpService.locations();

Comment: possibly the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> this.signUpService.locations();

*getters* are not *invoked*. They are simply *got*

## Fix:

```
const value = this.signUpService.locations;
```

[This is just TypeScript saving you](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/javascript/recap.html).