# Handling json objects in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a json object just like below

```
 response = [
{
  'a': [
    {
      'b': [
        {
          'c': [
            {
              'name': 'abc',
              'value': 900
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  'a': [
    {
      'b': [
        {
          'c': [
            {
              'name': 'abc',
              'amount': 900
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
];
```

now I am looping over the object using the code below

```
this.response.forEach(
    (event) => {
      event.a.forEach(
          () => {

          }
      );
    }
)
```

and while compiling it I am getting an error message

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: { 'b': { 'c': { 'name': string; 'value': number; }[]; }[]; }, index: number...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Any fix for the above error?. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature

Comment: What is giving you that response?

Comment: Maybe because you're using a parameterless lambda `() => { ... }` in the inner `forEach`. Using `(b) => { ... }` might solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.response.forEach((el1: any) => {
  el1.a.forEach((el2: any) => {
    el2.b.forEach((el3: any) => {
      el3.c.forEach(el4 => {
        console.log(el4)
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to access **c.name** and the **c.amount**

```
response.forEach(element => {
      element['a'].forEach(a => {
           a['b'].forEach(b => {
               b['c'].forEach(c => {
                     console.log(c.name);
                     console.log(c.amount);
               });
            });
      });
 });
```

JSFiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/jpwga2du/