# reduce array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I have an array of objects. I would concatenate items as follow:

```
obj2 = [{ rowNumber:33, rows:[{item1:'ItemOne'}]}, { rowNumber:44, rows:[{item2:'ItemTwo'}]}]  
===> new obj = [{ rowNumber:77, rows:[{item1:'ItemOne'},{item2:'ItemTwo'}]}]
```

Here's my code

```
let newobj=obj2.reduce((current , next)=> {
     current.rowNumber+next.rowNumber;
     current.rows.push(next.rows);
     return next;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj))
```

What actually get this only the second element

```
{"rowNumber":44,"rows":[{"item2":"ItemTwo"}]}
```

PS: I'm using Typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not updating the `current` object (which should actually be called `accumulator`). Also, you're pushing to `current` but returning `next`. Here's a fixed version.

```js
let obj2 = [{ rowNumber:33, rows:[{item1:'ItemOne'}]}, { rowNumber:44, rows:[{item2:'ItemTwo'}]}];

let newobj = obj2.reduce((current , next) => {
     current.rowNumber += next.rowNumber;
     current.rows.push(...next.rows);
     return current;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj))
```

I would fix the variable names in the reduce function to `(acc, current) => {...}` just to adhere to convention and so that it's clear that you want to use `current` to update `acc` and then return `acc`.

Comment: When using TS I get this waring in VS Code `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: { item1: string; }[]) => number) | ((...items: { item2: string; }[]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @infodev I don't think I can help you without more information. Perhaps you want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691889/error-cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the structure of your `obj2` array, you can go with the below solution, that will have be single object in the final with the sum of `rowNumbers` and an array of rows.

take a look, please:

```js
let obj2 = [{ rowNumber:33, rows:[{item1:'ItemOne'}]}, { rowNumber:44, rows:[{item2:'ItemTwo'}]}]

let singleObj = {
  rowNumber: 0,
  rows: [],
}
for (let obj of obj2){
  singleObj.rowNumber += obj.rowNumber;
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty('rows')){
    for (var row of obj.rows){
      singleObj.rows.push(row)
    }
  }
}
//HERE YOU CAN STRINGIFY() IT
console.log(singleObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you are trying to input the last element, *next*, to the first element, *current*.

As you know, Reduce functions allow you to take an array and returns a single value. It evaulates each element on the array one at a time, using the **last value to get a new value**.

So you should do something like this:

```js
let obj2 = [{ rowNumber:33, rows:[{item1:'ItemOne'}]}, { rowNumber:44,   rows:[{item2:'ItemTwo'}]}];

let newobj=obj2.reduce((current , next)=> {
 next.rowNumber += current.rowNumber;
 next.rows.push(current.rows);
 return next;
});

console.log(newobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Javascript Array.concat() method instead of push()

You can check it out here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat